# Installing Jquery using Bower in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, bower

When I use bower to install Jquery in my node project,the tree
structure of files that get created is as depicted in below image[/bower_components/jquery].

[image]

I use .js files in "dist" folder to include in my ejs views.

But I do not know the purpose of "src" folder , when and where it should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src` contains the library's source code. You only need it if you want to compile jQuery yourself.